# Filter chain halted as :redirect_admin rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-admin

When I try to login to my Rails application, I'm getting the following error in the logs:

```
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.136518 #13441]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 72.238.233.104 at 2016-10-03 11:44:17 -0500
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.139196 #13441]  INFO -- : Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.144634 #13441]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://www.myserver.org/admin/
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.144741 #13441]  INFO -- : Filter chain halted as :redirect_admin rendered or redirected
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.144949 #13441]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.394535 #13441]  INFO -- : Started GET "/admin/" for 72.238.233.104 at 2016-10-03 11:44:17 -0500
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.396819 #13441]  INFO -- : Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard as HTML
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.402503 #13441]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://www.myserver.org/
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.402686 #13441]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.650009 #13477]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 72.238.233.104 at 2016-10-03 11:44:17 -0500
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.651967 #13477]  INFO -- : Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.657941 #13477]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://www.myserver.org/admin/
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.658051 #13477]  INFO -- : Filter chain halted as :redirect_admin rendered or redirected
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.658498 #13477]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.909178 #13483]  INFO -- : Started GET "/admin/" for 72.238.233.104 at 2016-10-03 11:44:17 -0500
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.911936 #13483]  INFO -- : Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard as HTML
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.917690 #13483]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://www.myserver.org/
I, [2016-10-03T11:44:17.917845 #13483]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

and in the browser window I get:

```
The www.myserver.com page isn’t working

www.myserver.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Where do I begin troubleshooting?

I'm using the Rails_Admin gem for administration, Devise for authentication

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Here is my registrations controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
before_action :get_company_and_locations, only: [:edit, :update]

   def edit
     @card = get_stripe_info_by_customer(current_user.company.stripe_id)
     @last4 = @card.last4
     @exp_month = @card.exp_month
     @exp_year = @card.exp_year
   end

  # PUT /resource
  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:success] = "Your profile has been updated successfully!"
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end


  private

  def user_params
    # NOTE: Using `strong_parameters` gem
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :enable_notifications, :time_zone, :avatar)
  end

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation, :enable_notifications, :time_zone)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :enable_notifications, :time_zone)
  end

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_user_session_path
  end

end
```

**UPDATE:**
It looks like the controller specific to logging in as admin is in `application_controller`, so, here's the file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper

  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: ->(controller) { controller.request.format == "application/json" }

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :redirect_admin
  around_action :set_time_zone


  layout :layout_by_resource

  private

  def redirect_admin
    if current_user && current_user.admin? && !rails_admin_controller? && !devise_controller?
      redirect_to rails_admin.dashboard_path
    end
  end
```

I assume `:redirect_admin` is my problem since that's what the logs mention, but I don't understand why...

Comment: can u past your controller code?

Comment: Sure, which controller @SantoshSharma ?  I don't have a `sessions_controller` under my devise folder (never have), only a `registrations` one.

Comment: past your `registrations` controller

Comment: @SantoshSharma added both `registrations and application controllers`

Comment: Thank you. i am looking it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow... so, totally random, but I decided to change the timezone for my admin user.  Now I can log in.